# convert string[] to doube[,] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

i have text file consist of data like:

```
1,2  
2,3  
3,4  
4,5
```

Now I want to save the data into an array. So i do split:

```
using (streamreader sr = new streamreader("file.txt")) {
    string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
}
```

however my data save in string[] while I have a `GlobalDataClass` array declared as `double[,]`. Something like this:

```
static class GlobalDataClass  
{
   public static double[,] Array = new double[4, 2];
}
```

I need to assign the data to the GlobalDataClass:

```
GlobalDataClass.Array = data;
```

So my question is how to convert the `string[]` to `double[,]`?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a 2-d array, you'd need to iterate over each line and extract the values, then assign it into the proper position. You can use `Select` and `double.Parse` to convert the string values to double.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;
    for (var count = 0; count < 4; ++count)
    {
        var data = reader.ReadLine()
                         .Split(',')
                         .Select(v => double.Parse(v))
                         .ToArray();

        GlobalDataClass.Array[count,0] = data[0];
        GlobalDataclass.Array[count,1] = data[1];
    }
}
```

Now if your array was really `double[][]`, then you could do something more like:

```
GlobalDataClass.Array = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
                            .Select(l => l.Split(',')
                                          .Select(v => double.Parse(v))
                                          .ToArray())
                            .ToArray();
```

Note: I think it's like a really bad idea to make it a global variable. There's probably a much better way to handle this.

Comment: `ToList` here looks like overkill, since the structure of text file is regular (1 line - 2 numbers).

Comment: @Dennis - Yes, ToArray is probably better in this case. I just wanted to be able to index into it.

Comment: OP uses `double[,]`, you use `double[][]`. These are not the same.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - did you not see that I specified that the second example only works if he used `double[][]` in my answer?

Comment: @tvanfosson Your first example uses `[][]` as well: `GlobalDataClass.Array[count][0]`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - oops - fixed, I'm more used to using jagged arrays and just typed it that way without thinking.

Comment: @Ren - no, it's doing a direct conversion to `double[][]`, by reading all the lines at once, converting each to a `double[]` then wrapping the whole set up in an array. You won't be able to assign it to a 2D array; you'd have to change the type to `double[][]`.

Comment: ok. But is there any other way to convert it to double[,]? because the data my GlobalDataClass use double[,].Please advise..

Comment: @Ren - I gave you two solutions, the first uses the type you specified.  I don't think it's possible to either create a 2D array using LINQ or assign a row at a time.  You'll have to assign each individual element.

Comment: i try to use ur code,but then when i read the text file,it says input string was not in the correct format. any idea please?

Comment: @ren your file contains more data than what you've shown in your question

Comment: @tvanfosson I have corrected my data to fix the array, but now I'm getting this error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object" . Please advise..:(

Comment: @Ren I noticed that I had named the `StreamReader` "reader" not "sr" but hadn't updated the usage. I've fixed it now, you may need to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way is to use Array.ConvertAll.

Example:

```
string[] strs = new string[] { "1.00", "2.03" };
Array.ConvertAll(strs, Double.Parse);
```

Comment: does this support `double[ , ]` ?

Comment: I don't think it support double[,].

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
int counter =0 ;
 while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
    var lineData= line.Split(',');
    GlobalDataClass.Array[counter,0] =  double.Parse(lineData[0]);
    GlobalDataClass.Array[counter,1] =  double.Parse(lineData[1]);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: i try to use this code,but then when i read the text file,it says inout string was not in the correct format. any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of lines can vary:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
var data = new double[lines.Length, 2];

for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var temp = lines[i].Split(',');
    data[i,0] = double.Parse(temp[0]);
    data[i,1] = double.Parse(temp[1]);
}

GlobalDataClass.Array = data;
```

..or, if the number of lines is a constant value:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    var i = 0;
    var len = GlobalDataClass.GetLength(0);

    while (sr.Peak() >= 0 && i < len)
    {
        var temp = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
        GlobalDataClass.Array[i,0] = double.Parse(temp[0]);
        GlobalDataClass.Array[i,1] = double.Parse(temp[1]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don you re assign the GlobalDataClass.Array = new double[lines,2]? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Yep, in case there is a different number of lines in your 'file.txt', to avoid hard-coded values. But if you're sure that the number of lines is constant, then there is no need in re-assigning GlobalDataClass.Array

Comment: the GlobalDataClass already have the fix size array,therefore theres no need to re assign. i just want it to hold a value. Ex:  GlobalDataClass.Array = {{1,2},{2,3}...}

Comment: Almost there but I'm getting this error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object" . Please advise..:(

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] doubleArray = strArray.Select(s => Double.Parse(s)).ToArray();

int k = 0;

for (int i = GlobalDataClass.Array.GetLowerBound(0); i <= GlobalDataClass.Array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = GlobalDataClass.Array.GetLowerBound(1); j <= GlobalDataClass.Array.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        double d = doubleArray[k];
        GlobalDataClass.Array.SetValue(d, i, j);
        k++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
String [] words;    
int lineCount=0;
String [] Lines=File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Data.txt");
for (int i=0;i<Lines.Length;i++)
{
  words = Lines[i].Split(',');
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
  {
     GlobalDataClass.Array[i,j] = Convert.ToDouble(words[j].Trim());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using some part of your code to show you how you do this task.

```
int mCount = 0;
using (streamreader sr = new streamreader("file.txt")) {
    string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
    GlobalDataClass.Array[mCount , 0] = Double.Parse(data[0]);
    GlobalDataClass.Array[mCount , 1] = Double.Parse(data[1]);
    mCount += 1;
}
```